# Download zip folder based on form input - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, zip

I want to create search file form, where user search files based on year.I already made folder file in a years (ex. folder 2019, folder 2018, etc), so when user input value the results will show based on user input.  I get the result that i want, but i can't download file as zip because the value og path folder is null. I already tried use input-> get and session-> set_flashdata, but the result still null. My question is how do I get the year value, so can direct to the path folder?
**Note  : tahun is years in english**

**Controller**

```
public function download_zip() {    
// Read files from directory
$tahun = $this->input->get('tahun');
if($this->input-post('but_createzip2') != NULL){
// File name
$filename = $tahun . _laporan.zip;
// Directory path (uploads directory stored in project root)
$path = './uploaded/laporan/'.$tahun.'/';

// Add directory to zip
$this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE);

// Save the zip file to archivefiles directory
$this->zip->archive('./uploaded/backup_laporan/'. $filename);

// Download
$this->zip->download($filename);
}
// Load view
$this->load->view('v_detail_laporan');
}}
```

**View**

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'laporan'?>">
<input type = "text" id="tahun" name="tahun" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Tahun" required/>
</form>
// Download 
<?php echo form_open('laporan/download_zip'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are posting dat using GET method then why are you made condition in POST method

```
public function download_zip() {    
// Read files from directory
    $tahun = $this->input->get('tahun');

    if($this->input->get('tahun') != NULL){ // MODIFIED HERE YOU ARE PASSING VALUES USING GET METHOD 
    // File name
    $filename = $tahun ."_laporan.zip";
    // Directory path (uploads directory stored in project root)
    $path = './uploaded/laporan/'.$tahun.'/';

    // Add directory to zip
    $this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE);

    // Save the zip file to archivefiles directory
    $this->zip->archive('./uploaded/backup_laporan/'. $filename);

    // Download
    $this->zip->download($filename);
    }
    // Load view
    $this->load->view('v_detail_laporan');
}
```

> Try this code

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong form target, try to modify the codes be like below.

View :

```php
<?php echo form_open('laporan/download_zip', ['method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form']); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('but_createzip2','1');?>
<input type = "text" id="tahun" name="tahun" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Tahun" required/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller :

```php
public function download_zip() {    
    // Read files from directory
    $tahun = $this->input->post('tahun');
    if($this->input-post('but_createzip2') != NULL){
        // File name
        $filename = $tahun . _laporan.zip;
        // Directory path (uploads directory stored in project root)
        $path = './uploaded/laporan/'.$tahun.'/';

        // Add directory to zip
        $this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE);

        // Save the zip file to archivefiles directory
        $this->zip->archive('./uploaded/backup_laporan/'. $filename);

        // Download
        $this->zip->download($filename);
    }
    // Load view
    $this->load->view('v_detail_laporan');
}
```